# Search a table with multiple criteria - VBA(Excel)

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to built a search utility based on multiple criteria. My current code helps me do the search based on only one criteria.

I am looking to search based on Desc, Category (partial or full search), Price (e.g. >10, <50 i.e with any of the operators)

The below is an example data I am trying to search, I have also included the expected result scenarios too:

[image: Sample output]

Complete Data
Search

```
SKU Desc    Category    Price
1   Pen UTL 5
2   Pie1    FOOD    15
3   Pie2    FOOD    17
4   Pie3    FOOD    25
5   Pie4    FOOD    30
6   Paper1  UTL 4
7   Paper2  UTL 4.5
8   Paper3  UTL 10
9   Paper4  UTL 12
10  Paper5  UTL 14
11  Calculator1 UTL 50
12  Calculator2 UTL 70
13  Calculator3 UTL 90
```

Someone's help will be much appreciated here. My actual data will span up to 20K records.

The below is the current code: here I have the data to be searched in A4:D17 and the results are displayed at H:K

```
Option Explicit

Sub finddata()

Dim Catagoryname As String Dim finalrow As Integer Dim i As Integer 'row counter

Sheets("Data").Range("H5:k17").ClearContents Catagoryname = Sheets("Data").Range("J2").Value finalrow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))

For i = 5 To finalrow
    If Cells(i, 3) = Catagoryname Then
        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 12)).Copy
        Range("H100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
    End If Next i

End Sub
```

[image: Data]

Comment: What code do you already have? Add it to your post

Comment: what is the problem of the excel filtering?

Comment: You could use Userforms to add a Combobox that adds the Desc column without duplicates and then use the desc selected to Search with a Dictionary Object or .Find, or just filter

Answer (score 0):

@Ashwin, Here's little routine I use for searching on a partial name in a list of over 11,000 records, then I can autofilter on a category to narrow the list down. The results are posted to another sheet in the workbook, as I need to see all 36 columns in the results. If you require additional autofilters, then just add onto the end. I just use 2 inputboxes for the search because it has to be quick and on the fly. You should be able to modify any of the code to fit your needs. Hope this helps.

```
Public Sub SearchForItem()
  'SEARCH FOR SOMETHING AND OPTION TO SORT BY SOMETHING ELSE
Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim strValue As String
Dim lngRowOutput As Long
Dim result As String
Dim quest1 As String


result = InputBox(prompt:="What ?", Title:="First Search Item")
   If result = vbNullString Then
       Exit Sub
   Else
' where does the data end in Sheet1
   lngLastRow = Sheet2.UsedRange.Rows.Count

   If lngLastRow = 1 Then Exit Sub ' no data

' Clear down sheet2, assume we have column headings in row 1 we want to keep
   Sheet7.Range("6:1048576").Clear

lngRowOutput = 6 ' where are we going to write the values to in Sheet7 

For lngRow = 6 To lngLastRow
    strValue = Sheet2.Cells(lngRow, 2).Value ' get value from column B

    If InStr(1, strValue, result, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then ' can we find "First Search Item" in the text
        Sheet2.Rows(lngRow).Copy
        Sheet7.Rows(lngRowOutput).PasteSpecial
        lngRowOutput = lngRowOutput + 1
    End If

Next lngRow

End If

   'Go to the results and decide whether to AutoFilter or not
    Sheets("SResults").Select
quest1 = MsgBox("Do you want to select a category ?", vbYesNo)
  If quest1 = vbNo Then
  Exit Sub
  Else
 ActiveSheet.Range("$A$5:$AG$106").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=*" & InputBox("Operator to search for?") & "*"
  End If
End Sub
```